# Grails 3 respond method doesn't use defined JSON marshaller format

Tags: json, grails, controller

I currently define custom API responses for each resource using

```
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Something) { ... }
```

inside the BootStrap `init` closure.

Using `render something as JSON` gives me the desired output. Some properties of the domain class are filtered out according to the marshaller setup.

However, when I use the **respond** method, it does not use the marshaller format, but instead displays all of the properties of the domain class.

> Is there any way to make **respond** use the desired output set up by the marshaller?

*Grails version: 3.2.8*

Update:

It seems the problem arises when using the **rest-api** profile.

Comment: I think the new "grails way" of doing something like that is to use their Json views. I am using custom object marshaller's in a couple different grails projects and I have them all using the render function and not the respond function. Is there a reason you are set on using respond vs render?

Comment: @zypherman there will be less code if I use respond. And because some of the existing code in other projects uses respond. I was wondering if Json Views can be used in the same way, including for resources that contain nested resources within?

Comment: it looks like you can do a deep render which will render the nested resources. The JSON views docs are not super detailed but I believe you are able to specify how you want the output to look much like how you can do it in the object marshaler closure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem happens when you create grails application using profile: rest-api.
More precisely, the problem is caused by 2 conditions:

1. apply plugin:"org.grails.plugins.views-json" in build.gradle.
2. views/object/_object.gson exists

If you dive into 'respond', you will find:

```
renderer = registry.findRenderer(mimeType, value)
```

At this point, concrete class of renderer(Renderer) instance depends on whether conditions above are fulfilled or not.

- if above conditions are satisfied => **grails.plugin.json.renderer.JsonViewJsonRenderer**
- Otherwise => **org.grails.plugins.web.rest.render.json.DefaultJsonRenderer**

**(If you defined custom json renderer class for some class, that renderer would be returned here maybe. Custom json renderer is totally different from custom marshaller , so please ignore the case here.)**

When renderer == DefaultJsonRenderer, rendering logic finally goes to:

#### DefaultJsonRenderer.groovy:

```
protected void renderJson(T object, RenderContext context) {
    JSON converter
    if (namedConfiguration) {
        JSON.use(namedConfiguration) {
            converter = object as JSON
        }
    } else {
        converter = object as JSON
    }
    renderJson(converter, context)
}
```

so, this lead to the same result as 'render --- as JSON'.

On the other hand, when renderer == JsonViewJsonRenderer,
it does not refer to custom registered marshaller created by `JSON.registerObjectMarshaller`, but refers to gson view.

So, if you want to enable custom marshaller with keeping gson view functionality,
quick solution is, to remove _object.gson.

If you removed views-json plugin, no one can implement gson view in the application, which may cause inconvenience in the future.

Comment: so should I stop using json view?

Comment: so the problem is that the rest-api profile generates the file `grails-app/views/object/_object.json` which is used instead of the registered json marshaller. The solution is to delete that file. That way, respond should work fine, right @hitokun-s?

Comment: yes, you're right. I checked that in my demo app of the same situation. please try in your app.

Comment: @toshi This solution is not working for me in grails 4.0.1. I removed _object.json, still, my respond has renderer == JsonViewJsonRenderer. I need renderer == DefaultJsonRenderer for all my respond calls. Any ideas about how can I make it work with 4.0.1.